# Does GenerateScriptType support NonSerialized?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an object that's used both on the client and server side.

```
GenerateScriptType(typeof(MyClass))
```

However, there are some fields that I don't need on the client, so my question is there any way to prevent those fields being serialized? (For example, Field2 and Field3 in MyClass)

I tried marking the fields with [NonSerialized] but they still get serialized...

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Field1;
        public string Field2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private string _field3;
        public string Field3
        {
            get
            {
                return _field3 ?? (_field3 = "lala");
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,

Comment: Post real code.  Your MyClass doesn't even have the [Serialized] attribute.

Comment: I'm not aware that MyClass needs to have [Serialized] attribute, I'm just asking if there's a way to mark certain fields to not be serialized by GenerateScriptType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [ScriptIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for 4 months ago =p

Comment: You're welcome. As for the time, well, no doubt others will get here from a Google search as I did. And now they'll find an answer too! :)

Comment: ~ +1 from somebody who did just that (7 months after). :D